# Pass two variable in one array and show it on view page in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to merge two arrays into a single one and return it (the merged array) into a view in order to format and display it.

Below is the method in my controller intended for that purpose;

```
public function showJobCategoryContent($id)
{
    $jobsInfo = Job::where('category_id', '=', $id)->where('published', '=', 1)->paginate(3);
    $userInfo = Employee::all();
    $array    = array_merge($jobsInfo->toArray(), $userInfo->toArray());

    return view('front.category-content.job-category-content', [
        'jobsInfosById'=> $array
    ]);
}
```

Here, the content of my view;

```
@forelse($jobsInfosById as $jobInfoById)
    <li>
        <div class="well">
            <h4>{{ $jobInfoById['company_name'] }}</h4>
            <h4>{{ $jobInfoById['full_name'] }}</h4>
        </div>
    </li>
@endforelse
```

I get the following error:

> Undefined index: company_name

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you share your data structure?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$jobInfoById->company_name
```

instead of

```
$jobInfoById['company_name']
```

Comment: I tried based on this now this is show 'Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: can you share your array structure?

Comment: Array ( [id] => 3 [employer_id] => 16[company_name] => Khulan Computer house[published] => 1 [created_at] => 2017-10-22 15:25:54 [updated_at] => 2017-10-24 11:00:52 )

Comment: When i print $array it will show all data in controller and if i print_r $jobsInfosById on view page it shows all data but When i forelse($jobsInfoById as $jobInfoById) then print_r $jobInfoByid it shows only First Variable  Array which is $jobsInfo data

Comment: The problem is $jobsInfo and $userInfo is not array. it is object.

Comment: I have converted it as a array using  toArray()

Comment: Bro what i am trying to do that I want catch data seperateley  from two table then i want to show it using loop on view page how way i can do that.

Comment: i think you can not do that in this way. i am not sure. you can search array merge way. and how it works. And in your project you should do relation in your table and fetch all data from at a time using relation.

Comment: <h5 class="deadline">Deadline:<b>{{ date('d F, Y', strtotime($jobInfoById['created_at']->addDays(30))) }}</b></h5>  If i do it Then it shows "Call to a member function addDays() on string" how can i addDays(30) do you have any suggestion.